# Having issues with VBA Goal Seek - can't get the macro to work

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying different macros for a few days now without success.  I have a workbook that contains around 80 sheets.  I need to perform goal seek for all of the sheets beginning with the 3rd sheet.  Each sheet has a different "set cell" based on when the person's final payment is.  There is a formula in cell I5 and I6 that looks at I4 to find the final payment date (this date is a vlookup formula from another sheet), finds the matching date in column B (I5 = SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(MATCH(I4, B:B, 0), COLUMN(B1)), "$", "")) and then changes I6 to give us the "set cell" in column D (I6 = =SUBSTITUTE(I5, "B", "D")).

I need to use the value of what is in I6 as my "set cell", in this example, the set cell would be D5453, set to 0 by changing F4.  Below is my most recent version which is not working. The error I am getting is Runtime 1004.

```
Sub RunGoalSeekOnAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim changingCell As Range
    
    ' Define the target and changing cells
    Set targetCell = Sheets(1).Range("I6") ' 
    Set changingCell = Sheets(1).Range("F4") '
    
    ' Loop through sheets starting from sheet 3
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Index >= 3 Then
            ' Activate the current sheet
            ws.Activate
            
            ' Run Goal Seek
            changingCell.GoalSeek Goal:=targetCell.Value, changingCell:=changingCell
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: On which line do you get an error? What error? Your _Goal_ and _changingCell_ refers to the first sheet on each loop.

Comment: The error likely occurs because the goal seek is iterating through the same sheet for every worksheet, so as it moves onto the next sheet it's still looking at the first. You should move the section where you define the cells into the loop and use ws instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub RunGoalSeekOnAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim changingCell As Range
        
    ' Loop through sheets starting from sheet 3
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Index >= 3 Then
            ' Activate the current sheet
            ws.Activate
            'Define the target and changing cell for each sheet.
            Set targetCell = ws.Range("I6") ' 
            Set changingCell = ws.Range("F4") '
            
            ' Run Goal Seek
            changingCell.GoalSeek Goal:=targetCell.Value, _
            changingCell:=changingCell
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Because `ws` is already a worksheet you could use e.g. `ws.Range("I6")` in the loop.

Comment: @Shrotter good catch, i adjusted it accordingly, thank you. OP can likely also skip the `ws.activate` as well without an issue.

Comment: I tried with the updated code, but I'm getting a runtime error 1004:  GoalSeek method of Range class failed. with the highlight on changingCell.GoalSeek Goal:=targetCell.Value, changingCell:=changingCell

Comment: @Ecubugg Personally, I'd stay away from using the same word for changingcell as the syntax requires as VBA may see it as ambiguous. I also separated the line to if the error occurs on that line or the goalseek itself. And looking closer, I think the problem may also occur because the cell you are changing is also the cell you're goal seeking?

Comment: @Ecubugg FYI the first condition [cell].Goalseek should not be the same as the changing cell. This is likely the source of your issues. Looking closer it looks like your goalseek output cell is also adding a text value? You should likely revisit what you're trying to accomplish. Goalseek is used to change the hard-coded inputs of a formula to reach a desired calculation's end result. For example, Price is $10, you want 1.25M in revenue, so you would goalseek the units sold to determine how many units you need to sell to meet your revenue goal (simple example).

Comment: @MarkS. - thanks, this was super helpful, I have used goal seek manually for years, but I don't think I realized what I had done with the code (I'm fairly new to vba), BUT, I got it to work based on your help, so thank you so much!

Comment: @Ecubugg I'm glad you got it to work. If the solution works accept it as an answer, if it needed modification maybe submit your own answer that clarifies it. Whenever I'm in doubt in how something does something, I'll record the manual process to get the syntax and then take just what i need for my own code. Just be mindful that recording macros has some bad hygiene like selecting cells and activating them.